# Busca não funciona corretamente ao usar JOIN

Tags: mysql

Tenho a SQL abaixo e o parâmetro onde a parte `JOIN contratos co ON c.email != co.email` não está funcionando. Meu objetivo é que o `c.email` não esteja na tabela contratos. Não é mostrado nenhum erro de SQL.

Se eu faço assim `JOIN contratos co ON c.email = co.email` funciona perfeitamente... mas eu quero o resultado contrario disso.

```
SELECT os.osID, c.nome, c.email, os.idioma, os.dataAtualizacao
FROM os JOIN cadastroCliente c ON os.idcliente = c.cadastroClienteID AND c.email != '' JOIN contratos co ON c.email != co.email
WHERE os.status = '1' 
AND os.respondido = '1'
AND os.emailAutRecuperar1 = '0'
AND os.dataAtualizacao < CURRENT_DATE()-3 GROUP BY osID
```

Já tentei de outra forma mas tambem sem sucesso.

```
SELECT os.osID, c.nome, c.email, os.idioma, os.dataAtualizacao
FROM os, contratos co JOIN cadastroCliente c ON os.idcliente = c.cadastroClienteID AND c.email != ''
WHERE os.status = '1' 
AND os.respondido = '1'
AND os.emailAutRecuperar1 = '0'
AND os.dataAtualizacao < CURRENT_DATE()-3 AND c.email != co.email GROUP BY osID
```

Comment: você já tentou o operador `<>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já tentou usar `NOT IN`?

Esse comando iria filtrar `c.Email not in (select co.Email from Contratos co)`

```
WHERE c.Email NOT IN
(
SELECT co.Email from Contratos co
)
```